# Relative clauses (defining or non-defining)

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

There is a question in a test as follows:

> Combine these two sentences into one with a relative clause:
>
> *My brother is a great doctor.
>
> He works in a famous hospital*

My friend insists that there is only one way to do this based on the question, which is:

> *My brother, **who works in a famous hospital**, is a great doctor.*

He also said things about defining and non-defining clauses to support his opinion, but to be honest I didn't understand.

So, what about this construction?

> *My brother is a great doctor who works in a famous hospital.*

Comment: Your friend is ignorant. The last version is the "default" construction in English. You can tell that simply from the fact that it doesn't require any punctuation / special enunciation to get the message across. Your friend's version *requires* commas (pauses in speech), otherwise people will think you're singling out *specifically the brother who works in a famous hospital* as a great doctor (implying that you have *other* brothers who *don't* work in famous hospitals who *aren't* great doctors).

Comment: (Your friend is correct that the commas are needed ***if*** you've "inverted" the utterance to "front" the ***who-*** element. But the inversion itself is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Both structures work in this case *because* the "who works in" clause is "non-defining." And your structure has the advantage of being more straightforward.

What your friend is thinking of is: if the clause *were* a "defining" one, then the structure he proposed would be right (but without the commas). Let's say you've seen several doctors already:

> The person who you saw first is a great doctor.

Maybe the later ones were lousy.

In this case, "who you saw first" is a necessary clause; it explains who "that person" is. It *defines* them. The clue is that we don't put commas around it. But in the original example, "My brother, who works in a famous hospital, is a great doctor," the speaker hasn't added the "famous hospital" part to help us tell one brother from another. It's just a bit of extra information.

Answer (score 1):

> My fried insists that there is only one way to do this based on the
> question

Actually, there are many ways to do this:

- My brother who/that is a great doctor works in a famous hospital
- My brother who/that works in a famous hospital is a great doctor
- My brother, who is a great doctor, works in a famous hospital
- My brother, who works in a famous hospital, is a great doctor
- My brother working in a famous hospital is a doctor

In any case, if you don't use a comma, you define 'my brother'. Thanks to the 'who/that ...' part, it is clear who you are talking about. (Maybe you have several brothers)

If you use a comma, the ', who ...,' part is additional information. It can be removed and it will still be clear who you are talking about. (Maybe you have only one brother)